# Rails xml-builder custom namespace remove white space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-builder

I have a Google merchant centre XML script which is printing additional white space within every element and I can't seem to get rid of it

I've simplified the script below to demonstrate what I'm after. Current
script:

```
xml.instruct!
 xml.feed 'xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'xmlns:g' => 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' do
 @site.products.find(:all).each do |product|
  xml.entry do
    xml.g :image_link do xml.text!("http://www.mysite.com/{product.picture}"); end
  end
 end
end
```

Outputs:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <g:image_link>
  http://www.mysite.com/resources/images/pic.jpg
</g:image_link>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Notice that the image's url is on the next line and indented which won't work. What I need is:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <g:image_link>http://www.mysite.com/resources/images/pic.jpg</g:image_link>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

How can I resolve this please?

Answer (score 4):

To help anyone else with this issue in the future, how I finally resolved it was by changing the detail lines

From:

```
xml.g :image_link do xml.text!("http://www.mysite.com/{product.picture}"); end
```

To:

```
xml.g :image_link, "http://www.mysite.com#{product.picture}"
```

With thanks to: http://codalicious.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/product-rss-feed-for-google-base/